# I got this error in Monodroid "[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

When i running android app, the app getting crash for some time. I don't about this type of error, and i am new to android. How to resolve this app..

Detail Error:

```
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```